# How to preset modifiers?

Tags: modifiers, customization

Is there a way that I can set Blender so that certain modifiers have my presets on them? i.e. the boolean modifier presets to difference instead of intersect? This would be helpful, and time reducing, not just on boolean, but on other modifiers.

Comment: This only partly answers your question, but consider adding the native *Bool Tools* add-on. It enables you to set the boolean modifier and set the operand object to display bounds using Ctrl *, Ctrl - and Ctrl + on the Numpad.

Comment: More generally, it would be great to be able to instance modifiers between objects (shared reference)  as well as copying them... It would fit with the rest of Blender's philosophy.

Comment: For example, I want the boolean modifier to automatically be set to difference.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question in general about specifying your own defaults, but in 2.8, the default for Booleans IS Difference.

Comment: OK. I'm in 2.79, so thats why.

Comment: @RobinBetts You can already copy modifiers between objects using the *Copy Attributes* Add-on

Comment: @stphnl329 I think that copies them. What I was wishing for was _instancing_, so when you change the parameters in one modifier-instance, it's changed in all the others... You can do it with drivers, I guess..